# automating telnet with Groovy

Tags: groovy, osgi, gradle

I am doing a gradle/OSGi build.

I have the OSGi bundle building fine, but want to automate the bundle deployment.  I don't think there is a gradle task for this, so this becomes a groovy question.  To deploy to an osgi container you do the following:

1. telnet to the OSGi container port
2. send ss command to list the bundles
3. parse out the bundle in question
4. uninstall the bundle via a "uninstall [ID]" command
5. install the bundle via an "install file:///path to bundle" url
6. parse the results
7. exit telnet session.

Is there a way to telnet to a port using Groovy and send commands and read the output?

Thanks for any help,
phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about telnet, but I worked with Groovy and SSH using the AntBuilder and the sshexec task like this:

```
class SshClient {

    def host
    def username
    def password


    def execute (def command) {
        def ant = new AntBuilder()
        ant.sshexec(host : host,
                    username : username,
                    password : password,
                    command : command,
                    trust : "true",
                    outputproperty : "result")

        return ant.project.properties."result"
    }
}

def ssh = new SshClient ( host: "myhost",
                          username : "myuser",
                          password : "secret")

println ssh.execute("ls")
```

You will need the ant-jsch.jar and jsch-0.1.33.jar or higher in your classpath.

Comment: Very interesting. Can you execute multiple commands via one ssh session?

Comment: Yes you can: either by seperating the commands inside the command string using a semicolon or by using the commandResource property instead of the command property and pointing to a file that contains the commands that have to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

This should be simply doable with a normal socket and Stream Readers / Writer. Telnet is just a frontend for simple socket i/o that are text based protocols.

So, to do your steps:

- Create a normal socket to the destination host/port
- Write "ss"
- Create an inputstreamreader
- Consume everything available
- Parse to find your bundle id
- Send "uninstall " + bundleId
- Consume the stream until command prompt arrives / uninstall finished
- Send "install file://path/"
- Consume the stream until command prompt arrives / install finished
- socket.close()

Yeah, I know this resembles the steps you already wrote, but since telnet is not a real protocol, but just a frontend to text sockets, this should be easily doable for yourself.